# Can a 64-bit Windows app use an out-of-process (AX EXE) component?

Tags: com

A client is writing a 64-bit Windows app in some language (yet TBD) that can use COM. I have a 32-bit ActiveX EXE that includes functionality they'd like to include. All data to be marshalled between these would be simple 32-bit integers.

I have no experience in this area, but it seems like this should be possible. I've searched other answers here and many talk of using 32-bit DLLs in 64-bit apps but I didn't find anything on the point of out-of-process 32-bit COM servers in the same scenario.

Comment: @HansPassant Or else, make sure interfaces exposed by the EXE are automation compatible, and register a type library describing them. Would also help to have a TLB handy if "some language" is not C++.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Is there a model for the TLB that should be created? The server is OLE compatible, but was created in VB6 so most of that is hidden from me. I write TLBs all the time for components I build in ASM, so those concepts are no problem.

Comment: Examine the resources of your binary. I wouldn't be surprised if VB6 creates the type library and binds it to the EXE as a resource (typically, a resource of type `TYPELIB` with the ID of 1). Or, perhaps it exposes a pure dispinterface - that doesn't require anything extra to marshal, to the client it looks like `IDispatch` pointer. I've never used VB6 myself though.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik From what I remember about VB6 AX EXEs they are 'dual mode' COM so they likely do expose IDispatch. In that case is there anything needed besides the server itself? How would it get registered in the 64-bit world?

Comment: I don't believe anything needs to be registered differently. Just `CoCreateInstance` and ask for `IDispatch`. I don't know of any reason why it shouldn't just work.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That seems to be the case. Perhaps you could turn this into an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: And if it's a dual interface, you can ask for it as well, as automation compatible interfaces described in a type library will be marshaled by the type library marshaler, which is already registered for 32-bit and 64-bit.  This is useful if you want to avoid the cost of late-bound (by name) dispatching, or when `#import`ing in VC++.

Answer (score 0):

We just migrated an MS-Office-based application from 32-bit Office to 64-bit Office. The application uses a 32-bit out-of-process ActiveX EXE which was written in VB6 ages ago. Everything worked smoothly, no modification to the ActiveX EXE was required.

So, in my personal experience, the answer to your question

> Can a 64-bit Windows app use a [32-bit] out-of-process (AX EXE) component?

is **yes**.